# Show content for an specific item in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a list of Pipelines and their stages, I need tho show the stages of each pipelines when these are clicked. The thing is that I don't want to show them all, just the ones that are clicked...

[image: Something like this]
I have this code on my project, the thing is that with this it shows all of the stages of all of the pipelines, and I need just show the stages of the clicked pipeline. How can I dynamically link each other

```
     <div class="panel-body" id="body-pipelines">

            @foreach($pipelines as $key => $pipeline)
                <div class="pipelines">
                    <div class="col-md-3 row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 p-t-10 p-b-10" id="pipelines-sidebar">
                            <i class="fas fa-lg fa-fw m-r-10 fa-{{$pipeline->icon}}"></i>
                            <span>{{$pipeline->name}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="row float-right">
                        <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle" id="agregar"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sortable box row">
                            @foreach ($pipeline->stages as $stage)
                                <div class="stages txt username m-b-10" id="stages-{{$stage->id}}" style="background: {{$stage->color}}" onclick="javascript:;" data-type="text">{{$stage->name}} <div class="delete-stage float-right"><button class="btn  btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash" id="eliminar"></i></button></div></div>   
                            @endforeach
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: what is the problem and how are you trying to redirect? through js?

Comment: I was thinking of using Js but I there must be a way to do it through some Laravel sentences

Comment: why not simply use `<a>` and pass the url as href?